# Split array string in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to cpp and have a situation in which I want to split array string

I have

```
    for( i = k = 0; i < points[1].size(); i++ )
    {
        cout << points[1][k];
    }
```

Output >>

```
    [390.826, 69.2596]
    [500.324, 92.9649]
    [475.391, 132.093]
    [5.60519e-44, 4.62428e-44]
```

I want

```
    390.826
    69.2596
    500.324
    92.9649
    475.391
    132.093
    5.60519e-44
    4.62428e-44
```

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: What is `points`? Why does your loop body not involve the loop variable `i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the type of point has `public` members `x` and `y`:

```
for( i = k = 0; i < points[1].size(); i++ )
{
    cout << points[1][k].x << endl;
    cout << points[1][k].y << endl;
}
```

If the members are something else, say, `X` and `Y` (the uppercase), then use the uppercase instead (or whatever it is).

The reason why you code prints the output that way, because `operator<<` has been overloaded for the *type* of the point. Something like:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const point &p)
{
    return out << "[" << p.x << "," << p.y << "]\n"; 
}
```

If you can search the above definition (or something similar) somewhere in your project source code, and then can change that to  this:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const point &p)
{
    return out << p.x << "\n" << p.y << "\n"; 
}
```

then you wouldn't need to change the code in your `for` loop.

Comment: @Nim: Haha, it was just a guess that the type would have `x` and `y` as members.:D

Comment: That's not guess That's your experience. Anyways thanks it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with string splitting, what does `points[1][k]` actually return (i.e. it's *type*). Then look at how it has implemented the stream out operator (`operator<<`), and you'll see how the above is printed. This should give you a clue about the two individual values (i.e. fields of that *type), and you can simply access them and print them out.

Comment: can you please help me out with a link atleast

Comment: @WasimKarani, a link to what? I don't know what `points[1][k]` is, you are the one who knows... you need to look at the code.